# link option /INCREMENTAL:NO defeats function prolog disassembly, is it a bug in VSIDE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I find such a problem, if I pass `/INCREMENTAL:NO`([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally)) to link.exe, then VSIDE debugger sometimes fails to locate a function's start-address, or say, the function prolog is not disassembled correctly.

The vcxproj/cpp to demonstrate this is at: https://github.com/chjfth/trivials/tree/master/mswin/XdisProlog

The XdisProlog.cpp can be very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func2()
{
    int retv = 0;
    retv += 3;
    return retv;
}

int func1()
{
    int retv = func2();
    return retv;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int retv = func1();
    return retv;
}
```

To experiment, set a breakpoint at line #7 below, F5 starts debugging and the debugger stops at L#7 automatically. Now we see the prolog of `func2`.

With `/INCREMENTAL:NO`, my `func2`'s first machine instruction is not disassembled correctly.

[image: /INCREMENTAL:NO , bad disassembly]

Without `/INCREMENTAL:NO`, the result is correct.

[image: INCREMENTAL yes, good disassembly]

I tried VS2010 SP1, VS2019 16.11 and VS2022 17.6, all exhibiting the same behavior.

Can someone explain why this happens, or, is it a Visual Studio IDE bug?
?

Comment: You could give feedback to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Debug Information Format option will cause the disassembly to be different.

Eg.
/INCREMENTAL:NO and /ZI

[image]

Comment: It's right for `/ZI` (Hmm, not knowing why it must cause difference yet). But in my case (screenshots from my question shows that), `/INCREMENTAL:NO` does NOT produce different "mode" of assembly code, except that actual address for a specific function may be different, e.g., `func2`'s address is `0x00401000` vs `0x004075D0` .

Comment: I don't think you got to know my question clearly.